# Where should library #defines be declared if the library makes use of them?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

This may seem a rather silly question, but I have a header file for a library I am writing in which I am declaring some string constants:

```
#define CONST1 "Hello, World!"
#define CONST2 "Foo Bar"
// etc
```

The source of the library makes use of these constants, therefore I need to include the header file in the source:

```
#include <header.h>
void func() {
    printf("%s\n", CONST1);
}
```

This results in the end-user not requiring to include the header file in any source they are writing using the library. Is this the best practice or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the traditional approach. I would suggest (for clarity) that you prefix your preprocessor symbols with something that  makes them less likely to collide with user application code or other libraries.

I don't see how you mean with user code *not* needing to include your header, though ... Since these are preprocessor symbols, the header with the definitions is required if the symbols are of interest to the user program.

If the strings are only of use *inside* your library implementation, then you could perhaps move them to a private header to lessen the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. The strings are mainly used within the library, although they could be used externally as well. I will look into using a separate header for them.